# Does Aptana plugin help us iphone development in Eclipse?

Tags: html, ios, css, xcode, eclipse

i would like to know that,how can we do coding for iOS development in Eclipse??
i have heard that aptana plugin will help for that,if it is true how to use that plug in ?

i want to creating web apps in html which runs on iphone/ipad(thanks to [Jacky boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491239/jacky-boy) for reminding me about this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here. Either you want to develope native apps for iPhone/iPad and you use Xcode and iOS SDK. Or, you want to create web apps targeting the same devices. Since I didn't see HTML, CSS or JavaScript in the tags of the question, I am assuming you want native and in this case you should use Xcode.